# Local MySQL connection blocked on port 10050

Tags: mysql, debian

I have two servers both on local IPs and for some reason MySQL can't connect.

Source server: `mysql -u user_name -h 192.168.130.231 -p`

On the MySQL server I get a UFW block on port 10050 but am not running Zabbix on either end.

If I enable port 10050 I get the classic `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.130.231' (110)`.

Running `lsof -i -P` I can clearly see `mysqld     770           mysql   34u  IPv4  24813      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)`

And nothing is reported in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

Why would this not be working and would would port 10050 be coming into play?

Answer (score -1):

I use Linode and although I was connecting over a local IP the source server hadn't restarted to apply it. As such I was working on a `192.168.123.0/24` scenario.

I tried it from a different machine that I could apply the restart too and that fixed it.

I think Linode must use Zabbix somehow through their networking which is where this was thrown up.